# Unpacking With List vs. Brackets, Giving Unexpected Output Python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.5

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
l1 = (3, 4, 3)
l2 = (1, 2, 3)
print(*{x+y, for x,y in zip(l1,l2)})
```

Output:

```
4 6
```

The output I expected was 4 6 6

I may be mistaken, but I think it has to do with the unpacking with brackets because the code below:

```
print(*list(x+y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)))
```

Outputs:

```
4 6 6
```

Which is what I wanted. I was wondering, if anyone could explain the difference between brackets and list when being unpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in the first situation, using {}'s is a set. A set is a class for: `unordered collections of unique elements.` **It didn't print out another 6 because sets only contain unique elements**.

In the second case you create a generator which can contain non-unique or unique elements and therefore gives you all of the elements you added to it.

When in doubt, use the function `type()`, i.e. `type(< thing you don't understand goes here >)` to find out what you're dealing with.